# Unable to Load image from url in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am Fetching images from URL and it is providing broken images while on the web the same URL is providing complete and accurate images.

```
Scheme not starting with alphabetic character
```

throwing error.

```
// Depending on where the exception was thrown, the image cache may not
  // have had a chance to track the key in the cache at all.
  // Schedule a microtask to give the cache a chance to add the key.
```

Image Url:- https://smott.world/upload/source/1646761765-WhatsApp Image 2022-03-08 at 5.41.29 PM.jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your url is not encoded, you can encode using `Uri.encodeFull` to encode. Encode url will replace white spaces by `%20`

Example:

```dart
var uri = Uri.encodeFull('https://smott.world/upload/source/1646761765-WhatsApp Image 2022-03-08 at 5.41.29 PM.jpeg');
var url = uri.toString();

// url will be "https://smott.world/upload/source/1646761765-WhatsApp%20Image%202022-03-08%20at%205.41.29%20PM.jpeg"
```

You can see more about percent encoding [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)